# How do i update the max upload file size of php.ini in digital ocean app platform?

Tags: digital, ocean

I've deployed laravel to digital ocean app platform but i can only upload 2mb file using laravel i searched for php.ini and updated the max_upload_file_size but doesn't work how do i fix this

i want someone help who is good at digital ocean